# Pandas value_counts not found?

Tags: python, pandas

This seems very strange to me, but maybe there is an explanation of some sort. I have a data frame with ids.

```
>df 

Id   Value       Date
1      2         2012/03/04
2      12        2012/03/05
1      3         2012/03/06
1      9         2012/03/07
5      66        2012/02/08
```

When I do:

```
df.Id.value_counts()
```

I get:

```
1   3
2   1
5   1
```

But when I do:

```
df[df["Id"]==1]
```

I get:

```
Empty Dataframe
Columns: [Id, Value, Date]
Index= []
```

Am I just being an idiot somewhere? I'm positive that this is exactly what I'm doing,

Comment: Probably your `Id` column is actually composed of strings, not ints.  What does `map(type, df.Id)` return?

Comment: You got it again. DSM, you rock!

Comment: But no. I converted the column to float, and it still doesn't find the value that turns up 40 times.

Comment: We'll need to see a minimum reproducing case, then.  Find a small example where `pd.DataFrame(df.to_dict())` shows the problem, and then post the results of `df.to_dict()`.

Comment: @OlgaMu do ``df.dtypes`` to get a series of your dtypes indexed by their column name

Comment: Thank you, Jeff. I think I'm just going to do this in R, because I can't figure out how to get a sample of the (huge) data that will actually show the problem.

Comment: ok....ping us back if you need help

Comment: AAAAARH! There was trailing whitespace in the ids...

Comment: @OlgaMu try ``df['Id'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`` will force numeric (or you can do it when you read your data in)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,1,1,6], "Value":[2,12,3,9,99],
    "Date":['2012/03/04','2012/03/05','2012/03/06','2012/03/07','2012/03/08',]})

df[df["Id"]==1]
Out[24]: 
     Date       Id  Value
0  2012/03/04   1      2
2  2012/03/06   1      3
3  2012/03/07   1      9
```

DSM is right only problem that makes sense is that you have strings in Id.    Test with:

```
df.Id.dtype
Out[27]: dtype('int64')
```

if you get str:

```
    df[df["Id"]=="1"]
```

should work if you do not have any whitespace noise